# JuicyPixels texture loading in Haskell OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, haskell

How do I load a texture using Haskell, OpenGL and the JuicyPixels library?

I can get as far as this:

```
loadImage :: IO ()
loadImage = do image <- readPng "data/Picture.png"
               case image of 
                 (Left s) -> do print s
                                exitWith (ExitFailure 1)
                 (Right d) -> do case (ImageRGBA i) -> do etc...
```

How do I convert this to a TextureObject? I think I need to do a conversion between a Vector Word8 and PixelData (for OpenGL to recognize)

Comment: Note that this is partly what JuicyPixels-Repa was helpful for, but it needs updating for Repa-3.0 (GHC 7.4 or above).

Comment: Oops.  I forgot I had already done some work to update JP-repa for the new repa.   Yay.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use the [`texImage2D`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/OpenGL/2.5.0.0/doc/html/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-GL-Texturing-Specification.html#v%3atexImage2D) function. You'd invoke it like this:

```
import Data.Vector.Storable (unsafeWith)

import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.GL.Texturing.Specification (texImage2D, Level, Border, TextureSize2D(..))
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.GL.PixelRectangles.ColorTable (Proxy(..), PixelInternalFormat(..))
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.GL.PixelRectangles.Rasterization (PixelData(..))

-- ...

(ImageRGBA8 (Image width height dat)) ->
  -- Access the data vector pointer
  unsafeWith dat $ \ptr ->
    -- Generate the texture
    texImage2D
      -- No cube map
      Nothing
      -- No proxy
      NoProxy
      -- No mipmaps
      0
      -- Internal storage format: use R8G8B8A8 as internal storage
      RGBA8
      -- Size of the image
      (TextureSize2D width height)
      -- No borders
      0
      -- The pixel data: the vector contains Bytes, in RGBA order
      (PixelData RGBA UnsignedByte ptr)
```

Note that Juicy doesn't always give back an RGBA image. You have to handle each of the different image variations:

```
ImageY8, ImageYA8, ImageRGB8, ImageRGBA8, ImageYCrCb8
```

Also, before this command, you have to have bound a texture object to store the texture data in.

```
import Data.ObjectName (genObjectNames)
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.GL.Texturing.Objects (textureBinding)
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.GL.Texturing.Specification (TextureTarget(..))

-- ...

-- Generate 1 texture object
[texObject] <- genObjectNames 1

-- Make it the "currently bound 2D texture"
textureBinding Texture2D $= Just texObject
```

BTW, many of those imports are added automatically when you import `Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL`; you don't have to import each thing individually if you don't want.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think that it should be `UnsignedByte` rather than `Byte`. Other than that this worked.

Comment: For OpenGL 3.x (haskell package version 3.x, not OpenGL version 3.x) replace first argument of `texImage2D` from `Nothing` to `Texture2D`.